# How to append images as nodes in D3 force layout graph?

Tags: d3.js, svg

So I'm working on freecodecamp's D3 force layout challenge : https://www.freecodecamp.com/challenges/show-national-contiguity-with-a-force-directed-graph

And as part of the challenge, I'm trying to append images of flags as the nodes in a force layout.

I've managed to append the flags and they are showing. When you click and drag on them, the links also move too. The problem is that they are stuck in the same position.

This is what I mean:

[image]

javascript (it's made within React):

```
createForceGraph() {
    const { nodes, links } = this.state;
    console.log(nodes);
    console.log(links);

    const w = 800;
    const h = 500;

    const margin = {
      top: 30,
      right: 30,
      bottom: 80,
      left: 80
    };

    const svg = d3.select('.chart')
                  .append('svg')
                  .attr('width', w)
                  .attr('height', h);

    const simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
                         .force('link', d3.forceLink().id(function(d, i) { return i }).distance(1))
                         .force('charge', d3.forceManyBody().strength(1))
                         .force('center', d3.forceCenter(w / 2, h / 2))
                         .force('collision', d3.forceCollide(12));

    const link = svg.append('g')
                    .attr('class', 'links')
                    .selectAll('line')
                    .data(links)
                    .enter()
                    .append('line')
                    .attr('stroke', 'black');

    const node = d3.select('.nodes')
                    .selectAll('img')
                    .data(nodes)
                    .enter()
                    .append('img')
                    .attr('class', d => {
                      return `flag flag-${d.code}`;
                    })
                    .call(d3.drag()
                            .on('start', dragstarted)
                            .on('drag', dragged)
                            .on('end', dragended));

    simulation.nodes(nodes)
              .on('tick', ticked);

    simulation.force('link')
              .links(links);

    function ticked() {
       link
           .attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
           .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
           .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
           .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

       node
           .style("left", function(d) { return d.x + 'px'; })
           .style("top", function(d) { return d.y + 'px'; });
    }


    function dragstarted(d) {
      if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
      d.fx = d.x;
      d.fy = d.y;
    }

    function dragged(d) {
      d.fx = d3.event.x;
      d.fy = d3.event.y;
    }

    function dragended(d) {
      if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0);
      d.fx = null;
      d.fy = null;
    }
  }
```

HTML:

```
<div>D3 Force-Directed Layout
    <div className='chart'>
      <div className='nodes'></div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this can help you solve your problem?

https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/950642